# Differentiate different type of references in a project

Tags: .net, nuget, visual-studio-2015

In Visual Studio 2015, under references for a project, I noticed that Analyzers has a different icon/image than others.

I was wondering if there is a way to assign different icons to other types of references in a project so that you can tell at a glance where references are coming from (either NuGet or Project references or DLL references).

I think this is very helpful, especially when you are slowing moving away from maintaining your own references folder and start using NuGet and have a mix of both in a project.